# Proof of subgroup construction theorem

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, proof-explanation, abelian-groups

I am struggling to understand the proof of the following theorem:

Let G' be a subgroup of a finite abelian group G, where G' $\neq$ G. Choose an element a in G, a $\notin$ G', and let h be the indicator of a in G'. Then the set of products

$$
G'' = {xa^k:x \in G' and k = 0,1,2,....., h-1}
$$
is a subgroup of G which contains G'. Moreoever, the order of G'' is h times that of G',
$$
\mid G'' \mid = h\mid G'\mid
$$

The proof runs as follows:

First we test closure. Choose two elements in G'', say $xa^k$ and $ya^j$, where  x,y $\in$ G' and $0 \leq k < h, 0 \leq j < h$. Since G is abelian the product of the elements is 
$$

\begin{equation}
(xy)a^{k+j} \tag{1}
\end{equation}
Now
$k +j = qh + r \tag{2}$ where $0 \leq r < h$

I understand the rest of the proof if this claim is granted, but I'm not sure I follow the resoning here.

We know that k, j are both less than h, but why does it necessarily follow that k+j are greater than h, which would in fact imply that $k+j = qh + r$ (by Euclid's Algorithm).

I feel like I'm missing a trivial trick here....

Comment: What does "Let G'' be a subgroup of a finite abelian group G, where G' $\neq G\;$ " mean? What's the relation between $\;G,\,G',\,G''\;$ in that first line? What's the *indicator* of an element in a group?

Comment: My apologies, finger must have slipped. The first group is `G'`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question..... if $G' \leq G$ it follows that there may be elements $a \in G \notin G'$. If $G' < G$ it follows that there *will* be elements $a \in G \notin G'$... or am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, then $h$ is the order of $a$ in $G$, which is to say the least number such that $a^h = 1$

One way to think about $G''$ here is that it is the union of cosets $x\langle a \rangle$, where $x$ in $G'$ and $\langle a \rangle$ is the cyclic group generated by $a$. The argument that $G''$ is closed can be concisely summarized by saying that $G$ is abelian and both $\langle a \rangle$ and $G'$ are closed.

For the part in question, we're just saying that, since $h$ is the order of $a$.
$$a^ja^k = a^{j+k} = a^{qh+r}=a^{qh}a^r=a^r$$
It's ok if $k+j < h$, in that case $q=0$ and $r=k+j$.

Comment: derp... that last comment was exactly what I was missing. Thanks!